# How do I execute a remote pc's cmd?

Tags: networking, command-line, psexec

I have a computer at home, connected to a router with a fix internal IP (192.168.0.101). I forwarded a UDP port to it (:995), and placed the entire network under a dynamic DNS (no-ip), so I can access it via mstsc , with a path like  "mycomputerathome.zapto.org:123".

I'd like to access this machine's cmd. I've tried psExec's (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) solution, but whenever I try

```
psexec \\mycomputerathome.zapto.org:123 -uadminUser -p cmd
```

it returns

```
Couldn't access mycomputerathome.zapto.org:123:
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I ping'ed this location, accessed it via mstsc (again), double-checked user and password. All is up and running.
Is there a specific reason for it to deny my access?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you will not be able to specify a port as you have here. it violates UNC, and prevents psexec from managing its own ports, which is essential. you will need a tunnel to get you through your port fowarding, and then within the tunnel (VPN or SSH) you can connect via psexec without specifing a port number on the host parameter. psexec is a lan utility, so to use it over a wan, you need a tunnel to make it appear that the remote host is on the same lan you are.

Comment: @FrankThomas, thank you for your answer. Is there an application I can use to open a VPN connection for this purpose? Is Hamachi's LogMeIn fit for it?

Comment: @EricWu: Hamachi should do the trick, but **for personal use** you could also use TeamViewer (for free). That comes with a VPN and other functions. And both of them (as a feature) don't require you to use a dyn-DNS service.